# Write down the set in set build form $\{-1, 2, -3, 4, -5, 6...\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$$\{-1, 2, -3, 4, -5, 6...\}$$

I have been wondering how to rewrite the following set using the set build method because I have never seen such from before, the odd index is negative number while the even index is positive number

Answer (score 2):

That set is equal to$$\{n\in\Bbb Z\mid(\exists k\in\Bbb N):n=(-1)^kk\}.$$

Answer (score 2):

What about a simple one?
$\{1,2,3,4,5,\cdots\}$ is simply $\{n:\,n\in\mathbb{N}\}$.

Now, see: this one. $\{-1,1,-1,1,\cdots\}$ should be $\{x:\,x=(-1)^n\,,n\in\mathbb{N}\}$, right?

Combine both and the quoted set is thus
$$\{x:\,x=n(-1)^n\,, n\in\mathbb{N}\}$$

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 2):

For another way to write it down, it's $$\{(-1)^nn | n \in \mathbb{N}\}$$